# What actually makes internet explorer (in particular ie6) behave so differently

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am really getting tired of cross browser issues when developing - in particular finding hacks and workarounds for inconsistent rendering between browsers, obviously particularly IE and more specifically IE6.

I cant find any resources though that discuss the actual fundamentals of why they render differently and that acutally explain hacks/workaround instead of of just showing them.

Does anyone know of any such resources.

Comment: The why is simple: It is very old and buggy.

Comment: Keep in mind that IE is more than decade old.

Comment: What else could you expect from 10 years old browser? When it came out it was infact a really good browser compared to what was around at that time.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 was coming from a time that could be seen as 'pre-standard' competition, where formats and features differ.

Example:
E.g. when the Video recorder was developed, There was VHS but Philips bet on the Video2000 system. And that did not play content on VHS tapes. After the standard was chosen, VHS won... The same happens now with BluRay and HD-DVD. And in a way, this also happens with browsers, but at least hey play each others content but with different interpretations. You decided what is better: not playing a VHS tape in your video2000 system or with slighty buggisch colors. The last is what happening in the browsers.

At the time of IE6, the standards were not complete and everybody was rushing to get their browser out, regardless of standard-compatibility. Now, the world - like you - more or less recognizes the need for one standard. That will be HTML5.

Comment: All browsers are very easy to update, and they update themselves except IE... genuine advantage validation makes it difficult for an IE6 user to upgrade to IE7 and IE8 hence many people are stuck with using IE6 that is bundled with Windows XP.

Comment: Well, the question is why IE6 is not compatible, not why it is still in use. Anybody on XP can easily change to FireFox, Opera or chrome but somehow they do not. I think it also a part of lazy IT departments or inexperienced users.

Comment: Futhermore, IE updates will come autmatically with Microsoft Update (Unless you have problems with Genuine Advantage validation - either because you are fundamentaly against or you are using an illegal copy. In the latter part that is your own mistake)